# Rails 4 Active record, search by attribute that contains an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to search by an attribute that contains an array. I'm interested in returning all records where the array in this attribute contains a specific value.

example object

```
Location_1 {
  regions: ["on", "qc"]
}
```

I want to do something like this `Location.where(regions: "on")`, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax.

what is the right way to do this?

Comment: you want to get all the `Location` objects where region is either 'on' or 'qc' ?please elaborate with sample outputs

Comment: I want to get all Locations where regions contains some value, in the example above some value = 'on'

Answer (score 0):

Try this    `Location.where('regions in (?)', ['on','qc'])`

The `IN` operator allows you to specify multiple values in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Please do not post bare code, also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.